# Return an array after querying database in Java

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

I have to query a MSSQL database and I want the result of the query to returned as a Array or ArrayList.

I have a this code now, but it gives an error.
I have a connection to the database so that's not the problem.

```
public ArrayList<Array> queryResult(String q) throws SQLException {

   ArrayList<Array> array = new ArrayList<>();
   Statement statement = this.getConnection().createStatement();
   ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(q);

   while(rs.next()) {

      Array n = rs.getArray(rs.getRow());
      System.out.println(n);
      array.add(n);

   }
   return array;
}
```

I get the following error

```
Exception in thread "main" com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: This operation is not supported.
      at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:190)
      at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.NotImplemented(SQLServerResultSet.java:750)
      at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.getArray(SQLServerResultSet.java:2625)
      at server.Database.queryResult(Database.java:52)
      at server.Server.listen(Server.java:57)
      at server.Server.run(Server.java:34) at
      server.Server.<init>(Server.java:28) at
      server.Server.main(Server.java:94) Java Result: 1
```

Comment: btw you should use a try/finally construct to close your `ResultSet` and `Statement` objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getArray()` returns the value of a particular column of the current row as an array. See this - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getArray%28int%29

If you want to get row values as array then you have to write code for that some thing like this.

```
while (rs.next()){
     java.util.ArrayList alRowData = new java.util.ArrayList();
     java.sql.ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
     int numberOfColumns = rsmd.getColumnCount();
     for(int columnIndex = 1; columnIndex <= numberOfColumns; columnIndex ++){
          alRowData.add(rs.getObject(columnIndex));
     }
     System.out.println(alRowData);
}
```

Comment: Almost, "all the values of a particular column", should be gets the value for the column for the _current_ row as an array

Answer (score 1):

Your exception trace shows that:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: This operation is not supported.
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:190)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.NotImplemented(SQLServerResultSet.java:750)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerResultSet.getArray(SQLServerResultSet.java:2625)
```

Seems like the SQLDriver you used, did not implement the [`getArray(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getArray%28int%29) method, and hence is throwing this exception.

You may require the latest driver, support or an alternative solution to fix this issue.

**EDIT**:
If you really are looking to fetch current `Row` or `Record` of `ResultSet` then your call to `getRow()` and `getArray(..)` will not work and AFAIK such implementation is not available.