# Having Difficulty In Searching on My JAva Program

Tags: java, sql

I want to search some data from database and set it to jtable. So far I have written this code:

```
    try
    {
        String sql="select * from hotelinfo where Hotel_Name=?;
        pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setString(1,searchtxt.getText());

        rs=pst.executeQuery();

        hotelinfo.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
    }
```

this code is working but gives only one row i want whole rows which is related to my search

Comment: Make sure `DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel()` method do the correct way to extract the data from resultset.

Comment: Please add Expected output and the output you are getting.

Comment: I guess you should see this post. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10347148/return-an-array-after-querying-database-in-java
Its like what you need.

Comment: Do the data exists in table hotelinfor?

Answer (score 0):

As to your question, you should use like keyword in your select query instead of = sign.
Try with below code:

```
String sql = "select * from hotelinfo where Hotel_Name LIKE ?";

pst= connection.prepareStatement(sql);

pst.setString(1, "%" + searchtxt.getText() + "%");

rs= preparedStatement.executeQuery();
```

Comment: Not Working getting Same Problem

Comment: I am sure like keyword must use instead of = sign.As your know this is database knowledge.If not working, this problem is in this code hotelinfo.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));.Do you really rebuild and run.If right, could you provide please your resultSetToTableModel(fs) method??

Comment: If you use like, your search text no need to write exactly value in your database.